# AllVisible splitView on iPhone iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

A heard that is possible to show split view on iPhone in landscape mode on iOS 8? Is it true?

I tried:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.3
```

Everythings works great but only on iPad. On iPhone I have still full width masterView.

Comment: No it's not true. Only on iPhone 6 plus

Comment: that's what I thought but still I was hoping